# Reacting to edittext preference after value is entered

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm creating an app that uses an EditText preference in the preference screen. how can i perform some operation after I input some value into it and "OK" is pressed?

Answer (score 2):

in your activity's `onCreate`, add

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

and then implement

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(final SharedPreferences prefs,
    final String key)
{
  ...your code goes here...
}
```

you'll also add to your class declaration,

```
implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
```

Note: this is something you can do in your `PreferenceActivity` or in any `Activity`